# Create New appender using slf4j

Tags: slf4j, logback, appender

I want my messages to be added whenever we are logging something . For example if i am logging

log.info("Hello");

The message should be appended with some id which will be from my application.So the final logging message printed on console will be

Hello 1
Hello 2

Do i need to add an appender for this . If yes how can i achieve it using logback ?

Comment: I don't understand very well what u need. You would like add automatically an id into the message ?

Comment: Yes exactly i want some id to be appended into the message each time when we log something.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you manage this id yourself ?

Each time, you are logging something you can call the method with a parameter :

```
log.info("Hello {}", id);
```

But what is the interest of doing that ?
Are you trying to identify the session ?

Comment: Try with a sifintAppender maybe ? create a configuration with a discriminator and set the MDC value to identify what you want.

Comment: I will need to change the existing code in every log statements for that. I want to make sure that this id gets appended , so whenever i look at the logs i have that basic information.